# Почему Swiper Bundle работает только один раз для одного элемента?

Tags: html, css

Swiper Bundle работает только для одного *div*, куда присваивает элементы *css*, для других элементов с таким же названием класса не присваивает:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может ссылка устарела, потому что раньше всё работало корректно?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
```

Comment: Может код покажете?

Comment: Догадался поменять ссылку в *head* и *script* на:
`
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
`